# Vector, show body is in equilibrium

Tags: vectors

> Forces $F_1$, $F_2$, $F_3$ and $F_4$ act on a point on a body with the following vectors:
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> F_1 &= 2i - j + k, & r_1 &= 3i + j + 5k \\
> F_2 &= 8i - 6j + 6k, &  r_2 &= 5i - 2j -k \\
> F_3 &= 4i + 3k &   r_3 &= i - 6j = 7k\\
> F_4 &= i - 5j & r_4 &= i + 6k 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   Show that the body is in equilibrium, that is:

$$(r_1 \times F_1) + (r_2 \times F_2) + (r_3 \times F_3) + (r_4 \times F_4) = 0$$

So far I have this:

$$ F_1 = 2i - j + k \qquad r_1 = 3i +j + 5k $$

$$\begin{align}
F_1 \times r_1 = \begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k\\
- & F_1 & -\\
- & r_1 & - \\
\end {vmatrix}
&=\left( \begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 5\\
\end{vmatrix},\ -\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1\\
3 & 5\\
\end{vmatrix},\ \begin{vmatrix}
2 & -1\\
3 & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}
\right)\\
&= (5 -1)i -(10 - 3)j + (2-(-3))k \\
&= 6i - 7j + 5k
\end{align}
$$

So far i have got this far. I have worked out $$ r_1 \times F_1 $$.

So if i do for the rest. Then how do i add then up as it shows in the question?

Am i even right so far what I've done?

Answer (score 1):

I think your equation for $r_3$ should read $+7k$, not $=7k$.

To perform the addition just do vector addition of each of the cross products.